# ESP8266 serial returning 'garbage' to Arduino

Tags: arduino, esp8266

I bought ESP8266 module and I connected to Arduino UNO board through SoftwareSerial (PIN 10 - RX, PIN 11 - TX), 
I have also expternal power suply for ESP8266 5V (450mA) it reduced to 3.3V by step-down converter.

Connections:

ESP 8266

Vcc - 3.3V from external powers suply

CH_PD - 3.3V from external powers suply

GND - GND from external

RESET - not connected

GPIO - not connected

GPI2 - not connected

RX <- 5V from Arduino reduced to 3.3V by 3x10K ohm resistors

TX -> 3.3 to arduino

[Electrical connections](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xzsx9.jpg)

and I upload to Arduino sample program to test esp8266 communication.

Arduino program:

```
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>

const byte rxPin = 10; // Wire this to Tx Pin of ESP8266
const byte txPin = 11; // Wire this to Rx Pin of ESP8266

// We'll use a software serial interface to connect to ESP8266
SoftwareSerial ESP8266 (rxPin, txPin);

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  ESP8266.begin(9600); // Change this to the baudrate used by ESP8266
  delay(1000); // Let the module self-initialize
}

void loop() {

  delay(100);

  Serial.println("Sending an AT command...");
  ESP8266.println("AT\r\n");
  delay(30);
  while (ESP8266.available()){
     String inData = ESP8266.readStringUntil('\n');
     Serial.println("Got reponse from ESP8266: " + inData);
  }  
}
```

but i not working corectly... When Arduino send message to ESP. ESP returns only rubish.. withot "Ready" and don't get firmware information. I tested all speed baud it look's the same...

[Serial monitor - printscreen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LORUj.png)

When I manually send "AT" command from serial monitor EPS don't response anything!

Comment: Did you try any different baudrates?

Comment: which ESP module for you have, and what do the LEDs look like after 5 seconds of power?

Comment: Also, maybe connect the Arduino and ESP8266 grounds together.

Comment: ESP Tooking! :) I tested all combination of baudrates.
In Arduino program I set ESP baudrate to 74880 baud and open serial monitor with 9600 baud. And power off and power On ESP again ESP print:



 ets Jan  8 2013,rst cause:2, boot mode:(3,6)


load 0x40100000, len 1856, room 16 

tail 0
chksum 0x63
load 0x3ffe8000, len 776, room 8 
tail 0
k201 ot
 c9 r1Sd  o 
Fz:(1uu1
rf[112] : 03
rf[113] : 00
rf[114] : 01

SDK ver: 1.5.4(baaeaebb) compiled @ May 17 2016 19:23:54
phy ver: 972, pp v:.
˘�h’hńi×P¦9ń?ůkPx\‰§\�˘Ŕj§l'


Who knows what's that's mean?

Comment: @gre_gor thank's for yours help! I put it grounds together, and I think when module power on is tooking but it cant seen "READY" OK... Bad firmware?

Comment: Those are the bootloader messages. AT commands are transmitted over a different baudrate. Did you try 115200 or 57600?

Comment: Based on the answers given so far, it seems like this may be a hardware problem, which would make it [off-topic](/help/on-topic) here on SO. You might have better luck over at [electronics.SE] or [arduino.SE] Stack Exchange.

Comment: So was it the baud rate?  This happened to me and I had the wrong baud rate ... seems like a simple thing to check.  But I think it's OP's only question and not sure they are coming back.

Answer (score 2):

Connection is perfect. By default, the baud rate of esp8266 is 115200. So for the first time keep the baud rate 115200 both for esp8266 and serial monitor.

```
Serial.begin(115200)
ESP8266.begin(115200)
```

Now it is needed to change the baud rate of esp8266. Commands can be sent through serial communication.Use this command.

```
AT+CIOBAUD=9600
```

After this the above code should work as expected.

Answer (score 2):

Change the 10K resistor.Don't use it.When you use High value resistor it suppress the current hence you will not read any signals from that side.
Try using Low value resistor and in **9600 baud rate**

Answer (score 2):

If you want to program esp module with arduino uno you need to bypass the arduino and write the code 
Steps:
pins

arduino **tx-->rx** (esp)
arduino **rx-->tx**(esp)

3.3v supply -->**vcc,ch_pd (esp)**

GND -->**GND, Gpi0(esp)**

Baudrate works for me is **9600,57600**

Answer (score 0):

Do not use SoftwareSerial for Speeds above 19200 Baud.

Per default the ESP8266 talks at 115000 Baud. Connect it directly to the computer with USB/ Serial, use putty at 115000 Baud to talk to the ESP. Change the baud rate of the ESP to 19200 (AT+CIOBAUD=19200 for early FW version, AT+UARTsomething for newer).

SoftwareSerial should work than, but I don't use it any more - all kinds of problems; HardwareSerial is so much better. Just switch the Arduino RX/TX pins between computer and ESP; no monitor output then though; use the LED to give you clues.

Answer (score 0):

Use a logic level converter for the esp8266 Rx pin. Arduino logic is 5.0 v, and esp8266 is 3.3v logic.

Answer (score 0):

Make the ground of ext power supply and arduino common.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/18561498)